# Numbering lines of code with the <code> tag?

Tags: functions, tags, code

The wordpress  tag is used to display code on a page (refer to: http://themeforward.com/demo2/2011/09/12/code-tags-in-post/) but I am having a hard time finding a function that will number the lines of code, as seen on http://themeshaper.com/2009/07/02/wordpress-theme-search-page-template-tutorial/

Does anybody know where this function can be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get syntax highlighting with line numbering, you'll need to use a plugin like [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/).  In fact, looking at the source of that second link, it appears that they are using SyntaxHighlighter Evolved themselves.